# Inconsistent behavior with setTimeout when Chrome DevTools is not open

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

My intention is to create a basic debouncing function to search for employees. I found that when Chrome DevTools is open, I am able to consistently get search result from the server, but when Chrome DevTools is NOT open there are many times that the breakpoint set in the search method on the server is never hit. It seems that the AJAX call is not made for whatever reason.

Below the codepen, unfortunately I don't have the part that can return the search result.

https://codepen.io/jgunawan-dc/pen/vYLZbEY

```
new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 vuetify: new Vuetify(),
 data: {
  searchInput: null,
  selectedEmployees: null,
  isSearchingEmployee: false,
  items: [],
 },
 methods: {
  searchEmployees: function (searchInput) {
    // cancel pending call
    clearTimeout(this._timerId);

    this.isSearchingEmployee = true;

    // delay new call 1 second
    this._timerId = setTimeout(() => {
      let _this = this,
        url = 'some_url' + '?phrase=' + searchInput;
      url = encodeURI(url);

      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,         
        success: function (result) {                                              
          _this.items.splice(0);
          _this.items.push(...result);
        },
         complete: function (xhr) {
          _this.isSearchingEmployee = false;
        }
      });                    
    }, 1000);
  }
},
watch: {
  'searchInput': function (newVal) {
    this.searchEmployees(newVal);
   }
  }
})
```

Comment: sounds like `cache` to me. You probably have the checkbox checked on dev tools to "Disable Cache (while dev tools is open)"

Comment: Do breakpoints ever trigger with devtools closed? Maybe you should use `debugger` statement instead

Comment: @Matt the breakpoints are on the server, not the front end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GET requests are meant to be cached. That is what makes your surfing experience faster. So your browser is not hitting the server because it has the data.

DevTools has an option to not cache requests. You probably have this enabled, hence why you are always seeing the calls to the server.

[image]

If the data is static on the server, that is a good thing because that means it will be faster for he user. If you do not want them cached. Set the proper headers on the server so your requests are not cached. Another option is to set the JQuery Ajax parameter to not cache.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: url,   
  cache: false,
  ...
})
```

Comment: You nailed it. Setting the cache parameter on jQuery AJAX is not sufficient. I have to set the controller action on the server to turn off caching. Thank you.